# How to return back in SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have run SQL server command (update command).
the command has been performed successfully and the table has been updated

is there any way to take back in that command ?

note: no backup taken

Comment: please..please..and please..do check this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I believe the answer is "no".

Comment: **if** you've changed from autocommit mode (the default) to implicit transactions **and** you've not yet closed the query window from which you issued the update **and** you've not issued a `COMMIT`, then it's a simple matter of a `ROLLBACK` (or just closing the query window). However, that's unlikely, given that you're *asking* the question.

Comment: @SajadLfc i already reviewed that link and i think that i stick to the the criteria, don't i ?

Comment: In which recovery model is your database?

Comment: @EdwardDortland read the question and you'll have your answer. I'm guessing DEFAULT settings across the board.

Comment: it seems there is no way to cancel the updating after performing. :(

Comment: No, there is no Ctrl + Z in SQL Server.

Comment: i have learned new experience that to cover my command in transaction

Comment: ...and to take proper backups. That command exists for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have already executed an update command the only way back would be via restoring a backup.

Something I do when writing any modification scripts is to wrap the command in a transaction and then either run a rollback or a commit depending on if the query performed as suspected.

Example:

```
--start the transaction only execute the first three lines,  this leaves the transaction open
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE TABLEA
SET COL1 = "newValue"

--examine data and based on the results run one of these two lines
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 7):

If you had originally asked the question how do I do an `UPDATE` with the possibility of `ROLLBACK` I would tell you you should do your ad-hoc updates like this.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE blah
SET value = newvalue
WHERE condition = someothervalue

--COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Then if the results are as expected run the `COMMIT TRANSACTION`. If they are not than you could do a `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. However since you already did the updates and have no backups or recovery plan you are pretty much out of luck.